# Why am i getting an unexpected operator error in bash string equality test?

Tags: bash

Where is the error on line four?

```
if [ $bn == README ]; then
```

which i still get if i write it as

```
if [ $bn == README ]
then
```

or

```
if [ "$bn" == "README" ]; then
```

Context:

```
for fi in  /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/* 
do 
        bn=`basename $fi .ini`
        if [ $bn == "README" ]
        then
                echo "~ ***#*** ~"
        else
                echo "## Shortend for convience ##"
        fi
done
```

Comment: I tried making that change in the original script and i still get the error. I have done many tests. With quotes on either or both sites in simple tests if i set rme=README then do for example [ $rme==README ] && echo "equal"; output is equal. It does matter where the spaces are - with [ of course but also if you put spaces on one side of == they must be on the other. (I know bash.) I edited out semi-colons just in case i had a stray and that did not fix or change the line of the error.

Comment: Please update your question with the code is giving new errors. I touched a README file in a test dir and your code worked to me with my previous suggestion of `if [ $bn == "README" ]`.

Comment: @fedorqui Not without more quotes, no. And `=` rather than `==` if you want to be POSIX compliant.

Comment: You need more quotes elsewhere as well. For instance: `bn=$(basename "$fi")`; the quotes around the `$fi` (like all expansions) are mandatory.

Comment: Just because something still doesn't work when you fix a bug doesn't mean that bug doesn't need to be fixed. Anyhow -- use `set -x` to figure out the first place it's going wrong.

Comment: i edited it with the original script but i will try the answer that was posted in the meantime! :)

Comment: So `[ "$fi" = README ]` would be POSIX compliant, @CharlesDuffy?

Comment: @fedorqui Yes, `[ "$fi" = README ]` is POSIX compliant.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can't use == for single bracket comparisons ([ ]). Use single = instead. Also you must quote the variables to prevent expansion.

```
if [ "$bn" = README ]; then
```

If you use [[ ]], that could apply and you wouldn't need to quote the first argument:

```
if [[ $bn == README ]]; then
```

Comment: Xmm... On `bash 3.2.25` the `==` works with the `[ ... ]` syntax. Perhaps it is a version specific thing.

Comment: @user000001 On _bash_, yes, `==` works, but it's an extension -- the POSIX standard doesn't require it to work, so you're writing code that isn't portable for no good reason.

Comment: good tip on portability! AND.. this did not exactly solve it in the way intended. But the conversation made me realize .i am ashamed to say... not using bash -by mistake. I thought I was but NO. I was using sh by default. I forgot the line#!/bin/bash and was not using bash scriptname to run it. adding #!/bin/bash solved the problem.

Comment: @JohnHall It's still a good idea to quote your variables if you're not going to use [[ ]]. As an example, try this and you'll get an error: `A='a b c'; [ $A == . ] && echo a`

Comment: OK. Also i use "fi" in other programming language but it's not a very good choice for bash! I fixed that, and am a bit surprised it worked.

Answer (score 7):

Add the following to the top of your script:

```
#! /bin/bash
```

In bash, `==` [is the same](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) as `=` when used inside of single brackets.  This is, however, not portable.  So you should explicitly tell the shell to use bash as the script's interpreter by putting `#! /bin/bash` at the top of the script.

Alternatively, do your string comparisons using `=`.  Note that the `==` operator behaves *differently* when used inside of double-brackets than when inside of single-brackets (see the link).